# What is some advance reference books about alloy that gives a lot historical background and applies a lot of theoretical equation or formulas

Tags: materials, reference-request, alloy, books

What is some advance reference books specifically about alloy that gives a lot historical background and applies a lot of theoretical equation or formulas with explanation?

I seem to find nothing really very interesting for myself to learn general theory of alloy while searching the google books because these books is too wordy in detail but too few formula and laboratory skill to support it.

Comment: See if your library can get you something like http://www.amazon.com/Materials-Science-Engineering-William-Callister/dp/1118324579/, it's an extensive reference on a number of different materials.

Comment: You aren't going to find a lot- general metallurgy doesn't have a strong theoretical basis, its very experimentally based. Particular groups of alloy have a theoretical base but its only in expensive and university and propriety books.  A lot is fitting theories to experimental data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic would be Porter and Easterling's "Phase Transformations in Metals and Alloys", apparently still available. This should give you a good basis for understanding the thermodynamics of binary (and higher) systems.

For a deeper look at how computational thermodynamics is done, like CALPHAD, the Lukas, Fries, and Sundman book "Computational Thermodynamics" might do, but that has zero historical background.

You might also try asking this in Physics using the materials-science tag.